# Not able to iterate over second element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

Recently I was trying to iterate over javascript array where each element further have  2 elements associated with it, unfortunately when the first iteration is completed "for loop" is not iterating the second element it seems.

When I am using 2 elements for variable suppressCases value return is always FALSE but when I remove the 1st element from variable  "suppressCases"
I can achieve result value return is TRUE.

Below is my code

```
var suppressCases = [{
    "action-id": ["91471"],
    "checkSupressing": function() {
        return ["Poll", "Upload"].includes(ENV['Operation']);
    }
}, {
    "action-id": ["91470", "91469", "91486", "91476"],
    "checkSupressing": function() {
        if (resultCode != "0") {

            var ErrorList = INS('/soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Body/Response/Result/Error/ErrorList/CtlrError');

            if (ErrorList.length > 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var Type = String(IN(ErrorList[0], 'Type/text()'));
                var ErrorCode = String(IN(ErrorList[0], 'ErrorCode/text()'));

                return Type == "TV" && ErrorCode == "2020" ? true : false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}];

var suppress = false;


for (var i = 0; i < suppressCases.length; i++) {
    var suppressCase = suppressCases[i];
    if (suppressCase['action-id'].includes(ENV['action-id'])) {
        suppress = suppressCase['checkSupressing']();
    }
}
```

ENV[] is value from environment.

Can you suggest where I am doing something wrong,

Comment: It is `.includes` and not `.contains` ?

Comment: @JonasWilms, I did not get your point I have used 2 usages of contains, can you suggest where are you referring to.

Comment: both, there is no `.contains` method in js

Comment: Corrected but still having same problem,

Comment: Can you suggest how can I replace for with for each here?

Comment: Your code depends on too many variables that are not present in your example. Whether the functions returns true depends on `resultCode` a function called `INS()` and `ENVS`.  You should post a working example of the problem.

Comment: Hi, as mentioned if I remove the 1st element it will work further, I mean resultCode will have value.

Comment: @JonasWilms, you were right contains was a custom function implemented but when I used .includes I did not refresh the cache, Thank you for your help.

Comment: @hargun Glad to help :)